# How to find field with specific background using xpath contains

Tags: css, xpath, styles, contains

The field I'm looking for has below style:

```
background: #f3e6a0 !important;
```

I've tried locating it using:

```
//*[contains(@style, 'background: #f3e6a0')]
```

but it doesn't work, what do I need to change?

Comment: I can't replicate your problem - meaning your xpath expression should select the correnct node. Can you edit your question and post more of the html?

Answer (score 2):

Your expression match a element like this:

```
<div style="background: #f3e6a0 !important;"></div>
```

With his style as an html element attribute.

But no match elements that his style is definend in a separate css file or inside style html tag.

You could try select desired element by another way like csselector or select with xpath by other rule.